# What advantages do vectors have over linked lists

Tags: c++, list, vector

I had the following exchange with my professor which wasn't very satisfying. I included my parts of the exchange which should be enough to get my point across.

"For vectors, does the C++ implementation traverse through each element of the old dynamically allocated array and free it? 
(Edit: I mean, when resizing and adding elements, either by pushback or resize)

I am especially curious because the book tries to make the case that linked lists are troublesome because of having to traverse each time. Does not seem to me that vectors have a huge advantage in that regard.

The main benefit of the vectors I can see is the convenience and fast accessing but not much more. As in, everytime you try to do something other than accessing, you will be traversing through everything to move and free memory. Is that correct?"

After his reply, I added.

"Professor xxxx,

I went out to test, and in fact, the addresses change if you either resize or push_back, so my assumption that the old addresses are freed is correct. I can only assume that program will have to go to each element to free it, and if that's correct, won't the insertion of new things be costly in terms of time, even more so than traversing linked lists?

Can you kindly correct the following statement If it states any incorrect facts or assumptions. Using vectors in any other way than using arrays (for any other purpose than accessing already stored data), means that linked lists will almost always be faster because unlike linked lists, in vectors not only would you traverse through the elements, you will traverse through them, free them, and then create a whole new array to accommodate new space. That is because the next address after the last element of the current vector could have a pointer variable pointing to it, and using that address will cause an extremely strange behavior that I cannot imagine the poor soul's misery that tries to figure out what had gone wrong."

TL;DR:
Disadvantage of linked lists is traversing, but vector uses (push_back, resize(), etc) most often require the traversing anyway, so how are vectors exactly faster?

Comment: Inserting new things into a `vector` is **amortized constant time**. Sometimes it will cost a lot of time, but if you insert `N` things then the total time that takes will always be proportional to `N`. If you had to "traverse" every (or most of the) time, then it would be proportional to `N²`, but that's not the case.

Comment: (Inserting at the end of the vector, of course).

Comment: [some benchmarks](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html)

Comment: `vector` is used for and as a linear data structure to replace old `array` of `C` whereas `linked list` is and for non-linear data structures (i.e a singly or doubly linked list or trees etc). How are you going to use vector to represent a rooted b-tree or manage I/O of data in systems of very small memory?  If your requirement for college projects or assignments is simply to only store data of POD types in a contiguous block of memory, either one you find most appropriate or like can be used.

Answer (score 3):

There are several things that are faster than you expect:

- When a vector reallocates, the original elements are destroyed, not freed, one by one. Their storage is then freed all at once. This is as opposed to a linked list, where each node is allocated and freed individually. But this is somewhat moot because:
- A vector batches reallocations. `std::vector` is [specified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to have an amortized constant insertion cost, which implies that it avoids reallocating every time you `push_back`, to the extent that this cost becomes negligible when considering complexity. Typical implementations multiply the vector's capacity by a fixed factor every time it is exceeded, so when performing the costly reallocation it provides room for the next several `push_back`s. These then do not need to traverse the vector or allocate anything.
- A vector is extremely cache-friendly. This makes all sequential operations on a vector blazing fast, and can counter-intuitively outperform a linked list in many cases, especially in long-running applications where memory might become fragmented.

Comment: Made that statement more general.

Comment: The takeaway is that `std::list` is *almost never* faster. You use when you require it's (lack of) reference invalidation.

Comment: I will still harp on "amortized constant time". That's a really important distinction, and a way stronger statement than "generally won't reallocate every time" - it will reallocate _so seldomly_ that you won't notice on average.

Comment: @MaxLanghof does what I've written make sense? Don't hesitate to suggest an edit :)

Comment: And if there is known information about the needed size ahead of time, the `v.reserve(n);` can avoid reallocations altogether.  But if the size isn't known ahead of time, vector accommodates nicely.  (If the growth characteristic of the vector is such that it needs special treatment -- such as only growing by 100 reserved additional spots -- the `reserve(n)` can be used to grow more constrained than the baked in behavior.)

Comment: This answer clears my confusion very well, especially the amortized constant time insight. Knowing that vectors avoid reallocating whenever possible is a satisfying answer.

Answer (score 0):

*As a complement of the already given answer and comments...*

The `std::vector` has its elements stored contiguously in memory while it is not the case of a linked list.
The direct consequence is that element access is trivial for a `std::vector` while it's not for a linked list.
For example, if I want to access the *n<sup>th</sup>* element of a linked list, I have to iterate through the list until reaching the desired element.

But on the other hand, the linked list will perform better if we want to insert a new element inside.
Indeed, for a linked list, we have to iterate until we reach the desired position, then we just have to change the connections between the previous and the next node so that the new element is inserted in-between.
For a `std::vector`, you have to relocate every elements after the desired position (and make a reallocation if needed, i.e. if adding a new element exceeds the reserved available space).

So the `std::vector` is **better for element access** but is **less efficient when inserting an element inside** (same thing for removal).